# HttpClient Access failing in Xamarin PCL Project

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have this block of code in my Xamarin PCL project. However, on line 4 where it is meant to call the GetStringAsync method, code exits the method at that point and returns no response. I am unable to get json data from the web service and have tried several workarounds without success. I am using Visual studio 2015.

```
  //this calls the webservice
  public class RestClient<T>
   {
    private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:14241/api/Employees/";

    public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);

        var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

        return taskModels;
    }

    public async Task<bool> PostAsync(T t)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(WebServiceUrl, httpContent);

        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }

    public async Task<bool> PutAsync(int id, T t)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var result = await httpClient.PutAsync(WebServiceUrl + id, httpContent);

        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(int id, T t)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var response = await httpClient.DeleteAsync(WebServiceUrl + id);

        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
}


//this is the main view model that binds to the XAML page
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Employee> _employeeList;
    public List<Employee> EmployeesList
    {
        get { return _employeeList; }
        set
        {
            _employeeList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var employeeServices = new EmployeesServices();

        EmployeesList = await employeeServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName=null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}



    //method that calls the GetAsync() method to retrieve the employee list       
    //from the web service
    public class EmployeesServices
    {
    public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync()
    {
        RestClient<Employee> restClient = new RestClient<Employee>();

        var employeesList = await restClient.GetAsync();

        return employeesList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best thing to do is to run a communications traces (wireshark) to see what's happening at the network layer.  But before you do that...  just open a brower to the WebServiceUrl to see if you get a response.  Press the F12 key and watch the packets.

Comment: How are you calling this method? Are you just calling `GetAsync()` from within your application `main`? Do you have a [minimal/complete/verifiable example that could show us this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks @John, I have tested the web service url and it works as expected. It is actually in use in other applications.

Comment: @birryree, I am calling this method from a Services class that populates my view using the MVVM approach. Below is a sample call of the method from the service class

Comment: @ObinnaOsuji  I replaced your `WebServiceUrl` into new [json_test_link](https://d.jd.com/lab/get?callback=lab),and it return right response.So the issue happening at the network layer.

Comment: Ok time to run a wireshark trace to see if any packets are making it outbound at all...

Comment: @Nico thank you for the observation. I was able to determine that the issue was from the network layer and resolved it. I now get the correct response. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using `await` on the entire call chain all the way down to `GetAsync()`.

Comment: Yes, I am using await as seen in the following snippet - RestClient<Employee> restClient = new RestClient<Employee>();

            var employeesList = await restClient.GetAsync();

            return employeesList;

Comment: Is it wrapped in a void method at some point in the call stack?

Comment: No it is not, straight from the services class to the Binding Context of the main page

Comment: I have posted the full implementation of the code above. Thank you

Comment: Any chance you can post the code that uses the `RestClient` as well?